# How to add url through angular js script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could i add URL(href or sref) to title parameter which is inside for loop given in below code snippet.

I have tried with title:

`$sce.trustAsHtml("<a sref='#'>" + json1[int].comment + "</a>")`

and also tried with 
url: `$sce.trustAsHtml("<a sref='#'>" + json1[int].comment + "</a>")`,

but this didn't work.  Thanks in advance !!

```
        var calEvents = [];

            for (var int = 0; int < json1.length; int++) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(json1));

                var d = new Date(json1[int].reminderDate);

                calEvents.push({

                   //title: $sce.trustAsHtml("<a sref='#'>" + json1[int].comment + "</a>"),
                   title: json1[int].comment,
                       /*Here i want to add href/URL to title   */
                       // url: $sce.trustAsHtml("<a sref='#'>" + json1[int].comment + "</a>"),
                       start: d,
                       allDay: true
                    });
                   // alert(json1[int].comment);

            }

            $scope.events = calEvents;
            $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

Comment: What is an "sref"?

Comment: @shammelburg, we can create a link to this state using the ui-sref attribute

Comment: you will have to add `ui-sref` not just `sref` on its own, otherwise `ui-router` will not recognise its state.